# Size of a minimum generating set for full transformation monoids

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Given any finite set $X$ the set $\mathcal{T}(X)=X^X$ of all functions from $X$ to $X$ clearly forms a monoid under composition. Now if we call any family of functions $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{T}(X)$ a generating set of $\mathcal{T}(X)$ iff every function in $\mathcal{T}(X)$ can be expressed as a composition of functions in $\mathcal{F}$. Then how small can such a set $\mathcal{F}$ be while still generating every function in $\mathcal{T}(X)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minimal number to generate the full transformation monoids is 3 maps. You must include a generating set for the symmetric group, which requires 2, and then you can add any idempotent function collapsing exactly two elements.

Here are hints.

1. Use double transitivity of the symmetric group to show you get all idempotents collapsing exactly two points.
2. Show using 1 you can get any map collapsing two elements. (This is overkill to show every non-permutation is a product of idempotents.  Otherwise in step 1 get all maps collapsing just two points.)
3. Now do induction on the defect of $f$ (size of $|X|-|f(X)|$) to show you can get anything.

Comment: This can be found in virtually any book on finite semigroup including my book with John Rhodes the q-theory of finite semigroups.

Comment: It takes 3 maps all togethe to generate the full monoid. An n-cycle, a transposition and the map sending n to n-1 and fixing all other elements. I provided some hints.

Comment: Why is the $n$-cycle needed? It seems all you need is functions which move just one element, and then transpositions

Comment: To get 3 I can't use all transpositiins. The point is the monoid is generated by the symmetric group and any map collapsing exactly two elements and you can fix your favorite symmetric group generating set.

Comment: I think I get it. Is this result rather trivial then? Sorry I don't have any experience with this sorta stuff.

Comment: It is easy once you know the trick.  But people don’t learn it in a basic algebra course like generating the symmetric group by transpositions,

Comment: With a small generating set, it may take a large number L(pi) of compositions of generators for a given map pi.  Is there a slightly larger set G of generators which can sharply decrease the maximum such L needed?  As a first take, minimize |G|(Max L(pi)).  Gerhard "Wants To Get There Faster" Paseman, 2018.10.24.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, I'm sure somebody has computed bounds for this generating set on lengths. My guess is they are fairly good. You need at least one rank n-1 map. I suspect the key issue is generating permutations. And this is pretty efficient even though the inverse is not part of the signature. Then you can get all rank n-1 maps as fgh where f,h are permutations and f is your favorite rank n-1 map. To get a general map of rank r <n-1you can write it as a single rank n-1 map composed with a rank r+1 map. So it seems to me this is basically (n-2)+1+f(n)^2 where f(n) is the worse perm length

Comment: @GerhardPaseman For a lower bound, the number of compositions clearly has to be at least $(n\log n)/\log |G|$ in the worst case. For upper bounds: with the $3$-element generating set consisting of an $n$-cycle, a transposition, and a two-element collapse, $O(n^2)$ compositions suffice by mimicking insertion sort. Using bitonic mergesort or odd-even mergesort, it is easy to construct a generating set with $O(\log n)$ generators such that $O(n(\log n)^2)$ compositions suffice to generate any map.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, there exists a constant-size set of generators (5 or so) such that every element is the product of $O(n\log n)$ generators. This implies that for any $5\le g\le n^n$, there is a set of $g$ generators such that any element is a product of $O((n\log n)/\log g)$ of them, matching the upper bound in my previous comment. The basic idea is that if $c$ is the $n$-cycle, and, say, $n$ is odd, then $c^2$ is also an $n$-cycle, thus there is a permutation $d$ such that $c^2=d^{-1}cd$. It follows easily that any power $c^j$ can be written as a product of $O(\log n)$ ..

Comment: ... elements ($c$, $d$, $d^{-1}$). In a similar way, we may arrange that any transposition is a product of $O(\log n)$ generators, hence any permutation a product of $O(n\log n)$ generators. It is then easy to extend this to the whole monoid.